# CUDA kernel launch failed: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Tags: cuda, runtime-error, printf

I was trying to do a simple hello world on the cuda c++ program and I have tried various solutions round the stackoverflow and other docs, and I am bit confused as the code is getting compiled without any warnings and getting error during execution why it was not working for me.

Below are my sys specs:
Wed Feb  7 19:27:33 2024

[image: Kernel Info]

I have tried two different versions of the code i mean like the way of invoking the cuda kernel code like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__ void helloWorldKernel() {
    printf("Hello, World! from thread [%d,%d] in block [%d,%d]\n", threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, blockIdx.x, blockIdx.y);
}

int main() {
    // Define grid and block size
    dim3 blocks(1); // 1 block
    dim3 threads(1); // 1 thread per block

    // Launch the kernel using cudaLaunchKernel
    cudaLaunchKernel((void*)helloWorldKernel, blocks, threads, NULL, 0, NULL);
    
    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        std::cerr << "CUDA kernel launch failed: " << cudaGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Wait for the GPU to finish before accessing on host
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    // Check for any errors during kernel execution or device synchronization
    error = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        std::cerr << "CUDA device synchronization error: " << cudaGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Print a message from the host
    std::cout << "Hello, World! from the host\n";

    return 0;
}
```

In other version I just changed the way i invoke in main function so just providing the snippet of that below:

```
int main() {
    // Launch the kernel with a single block of a single thread
    helloWorldKernel<<<1, 1>>>();
    cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
    if (error != cudaSuccess) {
        std::cerr << "CUDA kernel launch failed: " << cudaGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

and incase i removed the cudaError_t error handling after calling the cuda kernel I am able to print the host output but not able to print from the kernel. can someone help me where do i am going wrong.

Comment: The error means that you have not compiled the code with support for your GPU. Probably because the Cuda toolkit you are using is too new

Comment: @talonmies can you eloborate a bit? is the toolkit is not compatible or not installed properly?

Comment: You have a very old GPU. CUDA 10.2 was probably the final toolkit release with support for Kepler architecture GPUs

Comment: switch to CUDA 10.2.  There is no need to reinstall the GPU driver.  Then compile your code with `-arch=sm_30` or similar.

Comment: @RobertCrovella can i know how to switch to kernel and execute ?

Comment: I don't know what " how to switch to kernel and execute" means.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -1):

As commenters mentionned, your binary probably does not contain device code usable for your device architecture.

You could inspect the content of your binary using `cuobjdump`. For example on Windows:

```
cuobjdump.exe app.exe
...
Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_86
code version = [7,8]
host = windows
compile_size = 64bit
compressed

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_86
code version = [1,7]
host = windows
compile_size = 64bit

Fatbin ptx code:
================
arch = sm_89
code version = [7,8]
host = windows
compile_size = 64bit
compressed

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_89
code version = [1,7]
host = windows
compile_size = 64bit
```

`elf code` is used if the device architecture matches exactly your GPU. Otherwise the driver uses the PTX code with the closest architecture to generate device code. This generation could take some time, but is generally cached by the driver.

For a commercial application, we usually recommend to generate device code for all architectures supported by your CUDA toolkit and generate PTX for the latest architecture; so your code will be able to support future new GPUs.